# What are the most notable attacks on pools?

Tags: mining-pools, history, theft

Since Bitcoin's inception there have been several attacks on mining pools. There was [the Linode problem](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3629/what-is-the-story-behind-the-linode-problem), where some 46,000 BTC were stolen from pool accounts.

What are some other notable attacks on mining pools?

Comment: Does a DDOS attack count, or only stolen data and/or coins?

Comment: @StephenGornick Latter are preferred, but any notable attack is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Exploits / Hacks resulting in BTC theft:**

- [The Linode Incident](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3629/what-is-the-story-behind-the-linode-problem) - 46,000 BTC were stolen due to the compromise of a single employee workstation.
- [Slush's Backup Hacked](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=66916.0) - 3094 BTC stolen after a backup of Slush's pool was compromised.
- [Mt.Gox Database Theft](http://www.dailytech.com/Inside+the+MegaHack+of+Bitcoin+the+Full+Story/article21942.htm) - a reported 100,000 BTC were stolen, and another 400,000 BTC reported 'missing'. Mt.Gox shuts down and stops honoring trades of compromised coins.

**[D]DoS Attacks ([Distributed] Denial of Service):**

- [Slush's Mining Pool DDoS](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9859/ddos-on-big-mining-pools-a-quick-way-to-51) - A DDoS attack which lasted nearly 2 days before being recovered from.

This is a CW entry in the hopes of creating a clean index of info about all known (and notable) attacks against mining pools. Please maintain it as new information becomes available.